# How to setup vuex store instance for recursive components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a component tree that uses vuex to share data. This component tree is supposed to be recursive. Each recursion should have its own vuex store instance. In the component tree's root I register the store like this:

```
beforeCreate () {
  this.$store = createStore()
}
```

When I access the store in one of the component tree's child via `this.$store` it always points to the *root* instance of the store.

This is what the recursion tree looks like (simplified):

```
- Recursion Level 1 (registers store)
  - Component (uses this.$store)
    - Recursion Level 2 (registers store)
      - Component (uses this.$store => points to Recursion Level 1's store)
```

The store's state is defined via a function:

```
state () { ... }
```

And the store itself is created by another function:

```
export default function createStore () {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    ...options,
  })
}
```

Comment: This depends on how are you using Vuex. Did you `Vue.use(Vuex)` and `new Vue({ store, .. })` Then your `this.$store` will always point to the store you passed while creating the Vue instance

Comment: You run a single instance of vue, no matter how many components you create, so "this.$store" will give access to the same object wherever you are. I recommend that you install the google chrome vue dev tools, that way you can view the state of the store